# How to resize an array using Principal Component Analysis?

Tags: matrix

Consider an array (`arr`) as

```
arr = RandomReal[1,{50,20}];
```

The `PrincipalComponents` applied on `arr` gives me an array of the same dimension.

However, in `matlab` `pca` gives me the coefficient matrix of `20 X 20`.

How can I do so in `Mathematica`?

Comment: @kglr It's giving me an array of `20X19`.

Answer (score 13):

It seems that *Mathematica* and MATLAB are doing different things.  *Mathematica's* [`PrincipalComponents`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PrincipalComponents.html) returns the principal components or "scores".  MATLAB's [`pca`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/pca.html) returns "the principal component coefficients, also known as loadings."
These are related to the singular value decomposition (see
https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/134282/relationship-between-svd-and-pca-how-to-use-svd-to-perform-pca).

Here is a MATLAB/*Mathematica* example.  The built-in MATLAB data set `hald` defines a variable `ingredients`, which is given as `ing` in the *Mathematica* code below.  If `{u, σ, v}` is the SVD of the centered data `ing`, then the coefficients are given by `v` and the principal components by `u.σ`:

```
% MATLAB code
load hald
[V, S, L] = pca(ingredients)  % returns coefficients V, scores S, component variances L


(* Mathematica code *)
ing = N@{  (* copied from MATLAB's ingredients *)
    {7,  26,  6, 60},
    {1,  29, 15, 52},
    {11, 56,  8, 20},
    {11, 31,  8, 47},
    {7,  52,  6, 33},
    {11, 55,  9, 22},
    {3,  71, 17,  6},
    {1,  31, 22, 44},
    {2,  54, 18, 22},
    {21, 47,  4, 26},
    {1,  40, 23, 34},
    {11, 66,  9, 12},
    {10, 68,  8, 12}};
s = PrincipalComponents[ing];  (* equals scores S in MATLAB *)
{u, σ, v} = SingularValueDecomposition[Transpose[Transpose@ing - Mean[ing]]];
u.σ == s
(*  True  *)

v  (* equals the coefficients V in MATLAB *)
(*
  {{-0.0678,     0.646018,  -0.567315,  0.50618},
   {-0.678516,   0.0199933,  0.543969,  0.493268},
   { 0.0290208, -0.75531,   -0.403553,  0.515567},
   { 0.730874,   0.10848,    0.468398,  0.484416}}
*)
```

Comment: the scores returned by Mathematica is not the same as returned by Matlab. The second and third elements in each row (in Mathematica) have the opposite signs compared to Matlab.

Comment: and for the coefficients as well.

Comment: @Majis The columns of $U$ and $V$ in the SVD $A = U\Sigma V^T$ are defined up to sign. (E.g. the columns of $V$ are normalized eigenvectors of $A^T A$ and each is unique up to sign, except when the eigen/singular values are repeated.)